# Extract images from a WMS raster map

Tags: raster, wms, xyz-tiles

How can I extract the complete map in high resolution images from a large WMS service raster map in QGIS? I have tried the XYZ tiles tool without correct results. Is there be a better option than XYZ-tiles to extract high resolution images from raster maps?

Comment: Hi Emily, welcome to GIS SE. Great to have you here. So you goal is to get tiles from a large raster image? If you don't describe in detail what exactly you tried, it's difficult to say what goes wrong. See [tour]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: WMS is not an XYZ tile (or indeed any type of tiling) API